# My Adobe Illustrator often froze because of sandboxd

Tags: macos, performance

The problem just started today. When using Illustrator, it starts to randomly freeze with the rainbow icon (mouse cursor).

When I check Activity Monitor, “sandboxd” used 93 to sometimes 100% of my CPU.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'd ask Adobe for support directly, given the money you're paying them.